# Load global bootstrap configuration in ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm using [react-universally](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally) as a ReactJS application boilerplate and bootstrap 4 for styling. Here is the main component `DemoApp`:

```
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';

import React from 'react';
import Switch from 'react-router-dom/Switch';
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

import config from '../../utils/config';

import './globals.css';

import Error404 from './Error404';
import Header from './Header';

import AsyncHomeRoute from './AsyncHomeRoute';
import AsyncCounterRoute from './AsyncCounterRoute';
import AsyncAboutRoute from './AsyncAboutRoute';

/// Should change the language below according to the user preference language

function DemoApp() {
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '2rem' }}>
      <Helmet>
        <html lang="en" />
        <title>{config('htmlPage.defaultTitle')}</title>
        <meta name="application-name" content={config('htmlPage.defaultTitle')} />
        <meta name="description" content={config('htmlPage.description')} />
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b2b2b" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicons/mstile-144x144.png" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#2b2b2b" />
        {/*
          A great reference for favicons:
          https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet
          It's a pain to manage/generate them. I run both these in order,
          and combine their results:
          http://realfavicongenerator.net/
          http://www.favicomatic.com/
        */}
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          sizes="152x152"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          sizes="144x144"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          sizes="120x120"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          sizes="114x114"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          sizes="76x76"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          sizes="72x72"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          sizes="57x57"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          sizes="60x60"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon"
          sizes="180x180"
          href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png"
        />
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#00a9d9" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
        <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b2b2b" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicons/mstile-144x144.png" />
        <meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/favicons/mstile-70x70.png" />
        <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/favicons/mstile-150x150.png" />
        <meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/favicons/mstile-310x150.png" />
        <meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/favicons/mstile-310x310.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />

        {/*
          NOTE: This is simply for quick and easy styling on the demo. Remove
          this and the related items from the Content Security Policy in the
          global config if you have no intention of using milligram.
        */}
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="/scripts/css/bootstrap.css"
        />
      </Helmet>
      <Header />
      <div style={{ paddingTop: '2rem', paddingBottom: '2rem' }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={AsyncHomeRoute} />
          <Route path="/counter" component={AsyncCounterRoute} />
          <Route path="/about" component={AsyncAboutRoute} />
          <Route component={Error404} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DemoApp;
```

And my `global.css` file, that styles all the application:

```
   html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Tangerine', serif !important;
      color: red;
    }

    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    /* Inline our ul for our menu */
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul li { display: inline; margin: 0 .5rem; }
```

My problem is that the font set (Tangerine) is not being show. It is being applied but then overwritten by boostraps `_reboot.css` that sets all font to bootstrap default.

I can imagine that this is due to the `import "./globals.css"` command that is being executed before loading bootstrap, so when I load bootstrap it calls `_reboot` to reset all parameter, includind its font, overwriting my settings.

How can I, using the DemoApp shown component approach, invert that order and load globals.css after bootstrap complete its setup cycle, so that my fonts can be used with no problems ?

If not possible, is there other solution availabe to setup bootstrap variables globally in a ReactJS environment ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You forgot a space here: `serif!important;` it is `serif !important;`

Answer (score 0):

You `globals.css` should override the global `bootstrap.css` or at least be applied after `bootstrap.css` has been loaded.

Since the file is global, you could create a Link after bootstrap:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="/scripts/css/bootstrap.css"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="/scripts/css/globals.css"
/>
```

Am I missing something?